# How to keep transmitting data from objective-C to swift after dismissal

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to get a live temperature as a constant (getting it from a bluetooth probe) to use in my entire project since a lot of screens need the temp data.

The sdk uses objective-c to communicate with the probe. What I'm trying to do now is to get this 'sensor1 reading' over to swift in order to turn it into a constant. I have managed to do this using the notification center.

When the user connects to their probe in the connect screen (backed by objective-c) the notificationcenter starts communicating with an observer on the swift side. This works great, until the connect screen is dismissed. When this happens, the transmitting of the notification center stops. The probe is still connected in the background. But I cannot get the live data over to my project.

Objective-c:

```
{
    id<TLDevice> device = [[ThermaLib sharedInstance] deviceList][indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TLDDeviceListCellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel *titleLabel = [cell viewWithTag:1];
    titleLabel.text = [device deviceName];

    UILabel *sensor1Label = [cell viewWithTag:2];
    UILabel *sensor2Label = [cell viewWithTag:3];


    if(device.isReady){

        // Check the device temperature unit and adjust the reading and suffix as necessary


        float reading1 = [device sensorAtIndex:1].reading;


        NSDictionary *myData = @{@"data1" : @(reading1)};
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reading1update" object:nil userInfo:myData];






        float reading2 = [device sensorAtIndex:2].reading;



        TLDeviceUnit unit1 = [device sensorAtIndex:1].displayUnit;
        TLDeviceUnit unit2 = [device sensorAtIndex:2].displayUnit;

        if (unit1 == TLDeviceUnitFahrenheit) {
            reading1 = reading1 * 1.8 + 32;
        }

        if(unit2 == TLDeviceUnitFahrenheit){
            reading2 = reading2 * 1.8 + 32;
        }

        sensor1Label.text = [[device sensorAtIndex:1] isFault] ? @"FAULT" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f %@", reading1, [TLDUtil stringFromUnit:unit1]];

        NSString *text;
        if ([device isSensorEnabledAtIndex:2]) {
            if ([[device sensorAtIndex:2] isFault]) {
                text = @"FAULT";
            } else {
                text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f %@", reading2, [TLDUtil stringFromUnit:unit2]];
            }
        } else {
            text = @"-";
        }
        sensor2Label.text = text;

    } else {
        sensor2Label.text = @"-";
        sensor1Label.text = @"-";
    }

    UILabel *batteryLabel = [cell viewWithTag:4];
    batteryLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld%%", (long)device.batteryLevel];

    return cell;
}
```

Swift:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName:NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "reading1update"), object:nil, queue:nil, using:yourFunction)

}
```

Comment: if you connect readings with just this one view controller it will not work, keep reading mechanism in a place that will live all the time

Comment: How would I go about doing this?

Comment: create it in appDelegate? make a singleton? there are different approaches, I don't know enough to recommend one

Comment: I understand I can do all that. My problem is that I can't seem to bridge objective-c with swift.

Comment: I cannot call for objects or anything else in swift that is created in objective c

Comment: nowhere in your post you gave example trying to use it, please post your code, I don't know what `I cannot call for objects or anything else ` means in this context